# Very high kernel procces time usage in new, idle server

Tags: linux-kernel, performance, monitoring, troubleshooting

We've recently installed a new server, which shows *very* high process usage in the kernel - as seen here with htop:
[image]

the cores and memory are reserved - so the usage is normal - but I've never seen this coming from the kernel (granted, I'm a novice sysadmin). I've tried analysing with the tool `perf`, which provides the following report:
[image]

the `cpu_idle_poll` instruction is causing the high usage, and I couldn't figure out how to further troubleshoot this online.
Just to clarify, the server is brand new and is doing absolutely nothing - as far as I know, it was not like this a few days ago when we just set it up.
I have a lot of learning resources but I'm kind of lost. If anyone can point me in the right direction - where I could look, what tool I could use, etc - I'd greatly appreciate it.
Willing to provide more information if neccesary, of course.

Thanks!
edit:
top output:
[image]

Comment: *Just to clarify, the server is brand new and is doing absolutely nothing - as far as I know, it was not like this a few days ago when we just set it up.*

`top` says something has eaten 56GB of RAM. This doesn't look like it's idling. There's a task running which is occupying almost all RAM. It would be great to see more lines from `top`. It would be great if you made the font smaller.

Comment: Thank you, but I am aware of this - the memory is reserved on purpose - it is part of how we set the servers up.

Comment: I'm gonna probably sound silly but I'd try another distro like Fedora 32.

Comment: Not an option, unfortunately - but I've deployed servers with the same distro (CentOS) and this has never happened before.